# How to graph multiple data sets in Android using Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, graph, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to display certain data in my app using a graph.

The data is saved in Firebase database under multiple nodes, [like the highlighted data in this database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g89cF.png)

Is there any library that can be used to make real-time graphs from Firebase?

Comment: Looking at your data, you don't need to duplicate things like `userid` and `detailId` you can access these through the `.key` or the query. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#key

Answer (score 0):

You might need to restructure your data, instead of storing the workout data in the `user` object, try breaking it out into it's own object.

```
/workouts {
  /{refPush} {
    date: '19-2-2018'
    name: 'Test Graph 2',
    set: '20',
    uid: 'someUid',
  }
}
```

Then you could access this information like;

```
firebase.database().ref('/workouts')
  .orderByChild('set')
  .equalTo('20');
```

Comment: I did have it like that before. But for the type of graph I want to show not one days "workout detail" but multiple days. so like if they put the same type of workout for 3 days in a row and so on. You can see the progression on the graph. So, i thought it would be better to put it directly under the "workouts" instead.

Comment: Assuming you always want to show the same `set` number then this would still work wouldn't it?

You can fetch all records with set 20 and grab the date from each object?